# Whether to use Green's Function or Laplace transform to solve the following partial differential equation in 3 variable?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation, greens-function

We denote
$$
f_x = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
\quad \text{and similarly} \quad
f_{xx} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}
$$
Let $T_a,a,b,c$ be constants.

How do we solve
$$
T_{rr} + T_r/r + T_{zz} = T_t/\alpha
$$

with boundary conditions:

1. $$k T_z(z=\delta) = \begin{cases}
   h(T_a–T(r,δ,t)), & rd \le r \le rp, T \ge t \ge 0\\
   -q(r,δ,t),       & rp \le r \le R,  T \ge t \ge 0, q(r,δ,t)= ar(b+ct)
   \end{cases}$$
2. $kT_r(r= R) = h(T_a – T(R,z,t)), 0 ≤ z ≤ δ, T ≥ t ≥ 0$
3. $T_r(r=rd) = 0, 0 ≤ z ≤ δd , T ≥ t ≥ 0$
4. $T(r,z,0) = T_o , rd≤ r ≤ R , 0 ≤ z ≤ δ$

It is a heat conduction equation representing heat conduction during the time of braking when brake and friction pad are in contact for a time interval $T$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please consider learning MathJax ( Math-parts of LaTeX ), as it is used for typesetting on this site.

Comment: Please, format your question properly using latex. Have a look a a guide here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: What is $T - T(Rd,z,t)$ ? Missing $_a$? Is $(r=r)$ really $(r=R)$? What is $q$? A free function?

Comment: Hi @Winther .. Its T_\alpha instead of T for the 2^nd BC. Also r=r_p and r=R (outer dia of brake disc). q is a surface heat generation function due to contact friction between pad and disc. Hope I have cleared your point. Thanks